# After retrieving multiple files I get an error on the next file '425 can't open data connection for transfer of file'

Tags: java, file-io, ftp

I'm using apache commons-net FTPClient (ver 3.3) and below error was produced on one of my clients machine (I've tried reproducing the error on my dev machine without luck using testing folder with the same requests on the same server with the same login)

I have a process that check's the remote FTP server for new requests in form of an XML-files. After listing all of those files i proceed in loop to check if they're in XML format. If the file is in this format I do first change their name by changing format from *.xml to *.xmlProcessing, retrive them to a input stream, parse them to my object and create a request in my queue and finally change the name and move them to subfolder working as an archive.

After downloading random amount of files I get stuck while calling retrieveFileStream on the next file, without a timeout or IO Exception.

I've managed to get logs from FTP server and it just says it can't open a data connection

```
05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > RNFR /folder/file.xml

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > 350 File exists, ready for destination name.

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > RNTO /folder/file.xmlProcessing

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > 250 file renamed successfully

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > PORT *ports*

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > 200 Port command successful

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > RETR /folder/file.xmlProcessing

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > 150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/folder/file.xmlProcessing"

05.06.2019 12:45:45 -  > 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/folder/file.xmlProcessing"
```

I've already tried diffrent FTP modes. Active local, remote, passive etc. (currently stuck with passive local mode).

I've tried the data timeout but it looks like while i finally got stuck on one of the files the method took more than 1 minute on that file despite me setting the timeout on 30s.

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
ftp.connect(server, port);
int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftp.disconnect();
    throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
}
ftp.login(user, password);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.setKeepAlive(true);
ftp.setDataTimeout(30000);
Collection<String> listOfFiles = listFiles(FOLDER_PATH);
for(String filePath : listOfFiles){
  if (filePath != null && filePath.endsWith(".xml")) {
     ftp.rnfr(folder + filePath);
     ftp.rnto(folder + filePath + "Processing");
     InputStream fileInputStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream(folder + filePath + "Processing");
     ftp.completePendingCommand();
     //Parsing file to an instance of my object and creating request
     ftp.rnfr(folder + filePath + "Processing");
     ftp.rnto(archiveFolder + filePath);
     if(fileInputStream != null){
    fileInputStream.close();
     }
  }
}
```

Is there's a bigger likehood that this is fault of the FTP Server, Firewall issues or something else ?

I've runed the same code from my dev machine and it processed all files from test folder (there were around 400 of them) i don't know if im being unlucky for error not occuring on my local dev machine or is it actually something wrong with communication of my contractor with the remote server ?

Comment: Isn't the transfer running faster on the remote server than on your local dev machine (e.g. because of a faster connection)?

Comment: That's almost certain. I do have only a laptop. And the process is deployed on high-end machine probably in the same host center as the FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you do a file transfer or a directory listing with FTP, the server (or client if using an active mode) assigns a random port number out of a configured range to that transfer. The port number is not released immediately, when the transfer completes. There's some *cooldown* interval. If you do too many file transfers in a short time interval, it can happen that the server runs out of the available ports – Because all ports end up in the cooldown state.

If you can, check the server configuration and configure a larger range of ports.

Or as a workaround, you can try to slow down the transfer rate.

For some background, see:

- [How many data channel ports do I need for an FTP?](https://serverfault.com/q/709984/168875)
- [Why does FTP passive mode require a port range as opposed to only one port?](https://serverfault.com/q/270745/168875)

---

*Though this is just a guess, you should check the server's log, as it can show more details.*

Another possibility is, that there's simply a limited number of transfers the server allows for a specific user or source address in some time interval.